# Como fazer uma expressão XPath num XML com vários namespaces?

Tags: xml, xpath

Tenho o seguinte xml:

```
<root xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <body xmlns="http://www.foo.com/bar">
        <checkCredit>
            <CheckCreditOut>
                <nomeSerasa />
                <addresses>
                    <id>9-CAZ7QCU</id>
                    <decision>ACCEPT</decision>
                </addresses>
            </CheckCreditOut>
        </checkCredit>
    </body>
</root>
```

Quero validar o valor do elemento **decision**, pra isso utilizo a expressão:

```
string(//decision) = 'ACCEPT'
```

E a expressão funciona, se eu remover algum dos namespaces do documento, do jeito que está, a expressão sempre retorna `false` pois não consegue chegar ao valor do elemento.

Como corrijo a expressão pra funcionar com 2 ou mais namespaces?

<sub>P.S: Também já testei usando o XPath `/root/body/checkCredit/CheckCreditOut/addresses/decision`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `local-name` do XPath:

```
/*[local-name() = 'checkCredit']/*[local-name() = 'CheckCreditOut']/*[local-name() = 'addresses']/*[local-name() = 'decision']
```

Comment: Olá, Ulysses, obrigado pela ajuda, testei a função e o problema continua, a expressão parece não encontrar o elemento (retorna String='').

Comment: Eu havia escrito errado e acabei de editar a resposta. Será que quando você testou ainda não estava com o erro? O erro era que o primeiro local-name estava com o valor 'video', que não tem no seu xml.